# Object not calling the value

Tags: c++

I am using the following code the object that I created in the following function does not call the values that I created in the main

```
void LoginScreen(){

UserInfo addUser[100];

string EUN, EP;
system("cls");
cout<<"Enter Username : ";
cin>>EUN;
cout<<endl;
//cout<<"Enter Password : ";
//cin>>EP


for( int a = 0; a < 100; a++){
    if (EUN == addUser[a].getUN()){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"OMG HELP MEEE ";
        //break;
    }
}
```

}

my UserInfo.cpp

```
 void UserInfo::setUN(string un){

    UserName = un;
}


string UserInfo::getUN(){

    return UserName;
}
```

my main

```
    void main()
{



    string tFname, tLname, tNumber;
    string tUN, tP;



    UserInfo addUser[100];



    cout<<"Enter Username : ";
    getline(cin,tUN);
    addUser[0].setUN(tUN);


    cout<<"Press 1 for tails"<<endl;
    cout<<"Press 2 for Login"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter Your Choice";
    cin>>main_menu;

    switch (main_menu){
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        LoginScreen();
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }

    getch();



}
```

I am not sure why its not giving the value in the loginScreen, but when I try to print the values in my main it works fine.

Comment: May be because you are again putting `UserInfo addUser[100];` in your function `LoginScreen()`

Comment: Ummm, how about you show us that main-function so that we might help you? This doesn't tell us all that much. But my guess is that you're doing something wrong with `scoping`.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa check the edited one

Comment: All that code doesn't make very much sense for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it yourself :

```
void LoginScreen(){

//you still want to use addUser from main, so what is this ?
UserInfo addUser[100];             -----------+
 ...                                          |
}                                             |
                                              |
void main()                                   |
{                                             |
                                              |
    UserInfo addUser[100];        ------------+
...
}
```

You can do something like this :

`void LoginScreen(UserInfo addUser[] ){ ... }`

Obviously you need to remove `UserInfo addUser[100];` from `LoginScreen` too

and then call it from `main`

`LoginScreen(addUser) ;`

Also, `void main` is not legal c++ use `int main`

Answer (score 0):

You must save the user list (or here array) as member of loginscreen.

except that, for style: when calling a function prefer `const string &`(setUN) and getters should be `const` here